# How to dinamically change the width of tabs in ICViewPager?

Tags: ios, pager

I'm using this library to make a ViewPager:

https://github.com/iltercengiz/ICViewPager

I'd like to know how to change the width of the tabs dinamically since they have different content:

[image]

There's a method where you can change the label yourself:

`- (UIView *)viewPager:(ViewPagerController *)viewPager viewForTabAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
}`

but I've tried to use:

```
    CGSize expectedLabelSize = [titleString sizeWithFont:label.font
                                  constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(400,200)
                                      lineBreakMode:label.lineBreakMode];
    [label sizeThatFits:expectedLabelSize];
```

and it doesn't work (nothing appears).

Changing the constant of the tabs is not enough since some of the widths are for example 50, and some of them are 500.

Does anyone have a clue?

Thank you very much in advance.